# How to calculate the download speed bytes/sec of a process

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

Could anyone tell me how to calculate the download speed of a process that are using a tcp socket connection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start to receive data, keep the DateTime.Now. When you receive from a TcpSocket, you get the size received.

Average = TotalByteReceived/(Now.TotalSeconds - StartTimeTotalSeconds)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
while(true){
TotalSize += client.GetStream().Read(buffer,0,count)
//logic for your buffer 
AverageBySecond = TotalSize / (DateTime.Now.TotalSeconds - now.TotalSeconds)
}
```

Comment: But measuring that away will not be conditioned to the speed of the machine?